# how to change pyspark data frame column data type?

Tags: dataframe, casting, pyspark

I'm looking for method to change pyspark dataframe column type

from

df.printSchema()

[image]

To

[image]

Thank you, for your help, in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to replace the column with new schema. ArrayType take two parameters elementType and containsNull.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
x = [("a",["b","c","d","e"]),("g",["h","h","d","e"])]
schema = StructType([StructField("key",StringType(), nullable=True),
                     StructField("values", ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=False))])

df = spark.createDataFrame(x,schema = schema)
df.printSchema()
new_schema = ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=True)
udf_foo = udf(lambda x:x, new_schema)
df.withColumn("values",udf_foo("values")).printSchema()



root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)

root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful example where you can change the schema for every column
assuming you want the same type

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = sc.parallelize([
Row(isbn=1, count=1, average=10.6666666),
Row(isbn=2, count=1, average=11.1111111)
]).toDF()

df.printSchema()
df=df.select(*[col(x).cast('float') for x in df.columns]).printSchema()
```

outputs:

```
  root
  |-- average: double (nullable = true)
  |-- count: long (nullable = true)
  |-- isbn: long (nullable = true)
  root
  |-- average: float (nullable = true)
  |-- count: float (nullable = true)
  |-- isbn: float (nullable = true)
```